# Google Sites: How to resize iframe based on the embedded content - Show full content instead of scrollbar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to create a google site with the google apps script where I am loading simple content from google sheet but after embedding the script url, the full content is loading within the the iframe fixed area with the vertical scrollbar.

Is there any way we can dynamically change the iframe height to fit the content so that it looks like a part of the google site?

[Google Sites - Iframe with scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH63v.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the code you're working on?